# Swing-Identify a line from multiple lines

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, line, shapes

I am drawing lots of lines which can move,resize.But,once I click on previously created lines its not moving.Only the latest line created is moving.Any suggestions so that all of my lines move at anytime.

```
MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 50, 50);
            prevPoint = e.getPoint();
            updateAction(e);
            ignoreMoves = true;

            System.out.println("Size:"+shapes.size());

            for (Shape shape : shapes) {
                if(shape.contains(prevPoint)){
                    System.out.println("Clicked Position is within a shape");
                    currentShape=shape;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Clicked Position NOT within a shape");
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("mouseDragged action:" + action);
            if (action != null) {
                switch (action) {
                case Move: {
                    //System.out.println("Move");
                    int dx = 0;
                    int dy = 0;

                    dx = (int) (prevPoint.x - e.getPoint().getX());
                    dy = (int) (prevPoint.y - e.getPoint().getY());

                    Line2D shape = ( Line2D ) currentShape;

                    int x1 = (int) (shape.getX1() - dx);
                    int y1 = (int) (shape.getY1() - dy);

                    int x2 = (int) (shape.getX2() - dx);
                    int y2 = (int) (shape.getY2() - dy);

                    Point startPoint = new Point(x1, y1);
                    Point endPoint = new Point(x2, y2);

                    if (shape != null) {
                        shape.setLine(startPoint, endPoint);
                        prevPoint = e.getPoint();
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
                    break;
                case ResizeEast: {
                      Line2D shape = ( Line2D ) currentShape;
                    Point endPointLine = e.getPoint();
                    shape.setLine(shape.getP1(), endPointLine);
                    repaint();
                }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            if (!ignoreMoves) {
                updateAction(e);
            }
        };

        protected void updateAction(MouseEvent e) {
            int x = e.getX();
            int y = e.getY();

            Point clickedPoint = new Point(x, y);

            int width = 0;
            int height = 0;

            double startPointX = 0;
            double startPointY = 0;
            double endPointX = 0;
            double endPointY = 0;

            if (shapes != null && shapes.size() > 0) {
                  Line2D shape = ( Line2D ) currentShape;

                Line2D line = (Line2D) shape;
                startPointX = line.getX1();
                startPointY = line.getY1();
                endPointX = line.getX2();
                endPointY = line.getY2();

                Rectangle rect = shape.getBounds();
                width = rect.width;
                height = rect.height;


                if (x > endPointX - 5) {
                    action = MouseAction.ResizeEast;
                } else if (rect.contains(clickedPoint)) {
                    action = MouseAction.Move;
                } else {
                    action = null;
                }
            }

            if (action != null) {
                setCursor(action.getCursor());
            } else {
                setCursor(null);
            }
        }

    };
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //System.out.println("Paint");

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);

        if (shapes != null && shapes.size() > 0) {

            for (Shape shape : shapes) {
                g2d.draw(shape);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Shapes is Null");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Point startPoint = new Point(50, 200);
        Point endPoint = new Point(100, 200);
        currentShape = new Line2D.Double(startPoint, endPoint);
        shapes.add(currentShape);
        repaint();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with Line2D.[contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#contains-double-double-)

If you read the documentation, it says:

> Returns: false because a Line2D contains no area.

My recommended solution would be to create rectangle2D's instead of Line2Ds, where the width or height is essentially the Stroke size (see Stroke). Also, you've have to rotate your Rectangle2Ds. The easiest way to do that may be to transform them into `Area`s (see Area), which was what I used when I created a [similar type of shape container](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape)

Comment: I also want to vary the width of the Line with the motion of the mouse in addition to rotation..can this also be achieved with your approach...?also,what would be the best approach for all this..viz rotation and varying width (with mouse) and setting properties on each line.

Comment: @RajTrivedi why don't you stick to your original objectives until you get that working?

Comment: Rectangle2D I cannot use as I need to draw an edge between 2 points...Rectangle2D takes one point and width which does not help my cause..